# RateIt.js Plugin won't work in a fancybox modal ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've tried to load rating star via fancybox. The star rating won't show up, mousing over them has no effect, although strangely enough the cancel mouse-over works. Has anybody tried using this rateit.js load via fancybox.

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vrferLfd/1/)

HTML :

```
<a id="chang3-bizname-link" class="add-input" href="#biznameupdate-form">Rate it</a>
<div id="biznameupdate-form" style="display:none;">
    <a class="rateit" id="rateit12" data-rateit-value = 3.5>Rate</a>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#chang3-bizname-link").fancybox();
});
```

Comment: could you provide some code and a working example. JSfiddle maybe?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vrferLfd/